# Connect to Neo4j Cluster via Rest-Interface

Tags: node.js, rest, neo4j

I am currently picking a database for my next project (node.js) and I have a question that needs to be answered before I can make a final decision.

I wanted to know if it was possible to setup a HA cluster and connect to it via the REST interface. The most likely solution that comes to my mind is to put HAproxy in front so that it evenly distributes the requests amongst the Neo4j servers. But what about transactions because HAproxy could easily send two requests that belong to the same transaction to different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe for writing to an HA cluster, writing to the slaves isn't any faster than just writing to the master since the slaves need to sync with the master.

Comment: so what you are saying is that the solution with the HA proxy works and that I should configure it in a way so that all POST, PUT, DELETE (i.e. all write operations) requests are relayed to the master and GET requests (all read operations) are evenly distributed. If that works than I think I have my answer.

Comment: thats correct.  Should work out nicely.  In general (depending on your hardware and use case) I would recommend keeping reading only to slaves and writes (as there is some serious overhead with writes) only to master.